# LARAVEL - Como compartilhar imagens entre projetos

Tags: php, laravel, linux

Eu tenho vários projetos `Laravel` num mesmo servidor. Frequentemente, necessito usar fotos de funcionários e, do jeito que tenho programado, eu copio as fotos do diretório `public/assets/`imagens de um projeto existente para o mesmo diretório do projeto em desenvolvimento, ocasionando um aumento muito grande de arquivos repetidos. Há alguma maneira de se compartilhar as fotos entre projetos ou ter um repositório comum?

Vi que existe um recurso no Laravel, que é o uso de 'symbolick link',  mas não entendi absolutamente como fazer.

Abaixo, faço um exemplo da ideia que eu estou tentando abordar, sem saber se este é o caminho.
O código é do projeto em desenvolvimento, necessitando pegar o caminho da foto de outro projeto existente, usando a palavra caminhoArquivo como este apontamento:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src='+caminhoArquivo+'+retorno[i].foto+'" style="width:50%;height:auto;" />
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Seria possível?

Comment: Se criar um sub-dominio apontado para esse diretório e utilizar nos outros sites?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o meu problema, que deve ser mesmo particular, é que tentei referenciar a uma pasta comum no servido usando um path absoluto, mas, não sei se é impedimento do Laravel, nunca dá certo. Sempre diz que o caminho não existe e coisa assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o symbolic link nativo do Laravel é para um mapeamento de diretórios de um único projeto.

O que você pode fazer é criar um diretório padrão na sua estrutura de arquivos, e fazer uma ligação simbólica deste diretório em uma subpasta de `storage/app` de cada um dos projetos, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
mkdir /var/www/shared-files
cd /var/www/prj-1/storage
mkdir app/files
ln -s /var/www/shared-files/* app/files
cd /var/www/prj-2/storage
app/files
ln -s /var/www/shared-files/* app/files
```

E assim por diante em cada um dos projetos.

Comment: Ademir Mazer, eu não entendo de Linux, mas acompanho suas instruções assim: a) cria-se uma pasta de nome shared-files e será nela que os arquivos em comum ficarão; b) troca-se o diretório para 'var/www/prj-1/storage', (o qual eu não sei o que é); c) cria-se a pasta 'app/files' neste diretório; d)  pasta que tem os arquivos comuns é mapeada com o comando do 'ln'. Neste ponto, eu não entendi qual foi o 'apelido' do mapeamento. Além disto, estou sob Windows.

Comment: Eu fui no Windows e vi como criar o 'symbolic link'. No meu caso, as imagens que desejo compartilhar estão em c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\avaliacao\public\assets\imagens'. O diretório do meu projeto, onde deveriam estar tais imagens é muito parecido: c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\pessoas\public\assets\imagens. Então, eu comandei no prompt do Windows do servidor, como Administrador, o seguinte: mklink /d "c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\pessoas\public\assets\imagens\imagem_remota" "c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\avaliacao\public\assets\imagens". No meu projeto, pus  'imagem_remota' como path mas deu 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Continuando, 403 (Forbidden) é uma proteção do Apache. Vi que queria de modificar o arquivo httpd.conf, no bloco <Directory> e, pelo que entendi, pôr lá uma permissão para o link simbólico. Escrevi lá, meio tateando no escuro, <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/avaliacao/public/assets/imagens">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>, salvei, derrubei o Apache e levantei novamente. Fui no meu projeto novo, referenciei ao nome do link simbólico criado (imagem_remota) e aí funcionou!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu acertar em Windows, não uso ele e não saberia como detalhar os passos para a sugestão que propus